# Returning two object from a function without an ArrayList

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm not sure how to word this correctly, but I'm told to write a method that would return the largest course object (the course with the most students). If there are two courses that have the same number of students, it would return both.

The second part of the problem is what troubles me, because I'm not allowed to make another `ArrayList` other than the ones he specified (which is already used). Is there a way to keep track of two+ objects without using an list/hash?

This is what I've done so far, but it only returns one course object.

```java
public Course largestEnrollment(){
    int size = 0;
    Course p = null;
    for (Integer c : courseList.keySet()){
        if (courseList.get(c).getClassList().size() > size){
            p = courseList.get(c);
            size = courseList.get(c).getClassList().size();
        }
        return p;            
    }
    return null;        
}
```

Comment: Course[] or Iterator<Course>. A lot depends on the exact wording of the limitation in the question.

Comment: I would ask your professor to clarify what exactly they want returned. In general, I would expect them to provide the function signature (the `public Course largestEnrollment()` part).

Answer (score 2):

Return an array of `Course` objects:

```
public Course[] largestEnrollment(){
```

You'll need to decide how to manipulate the array inside your `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the `ArrayList` based on size. Then you can return a [sub-list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) of the largest courses.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have so many `Course` (e.g. <1k), you could implement `Comparable` or write a `Comparator` for your `Course` object. So that you could just from the map get all Values(Course) in collection, then sort the collection, just from the end of the sorted collection take those elements with same values(size).

I mentioned the size of the collection because sort make the `O(n)` problem into `O(nlogn)`. But if the size is small, it is a convenient way to go.

Anyway, you have to change the method return type to a collection or an array.

Answer (score 1):

Sort then return a sublist:

```
public List<Course> largestEnrollment(List<Course> courses) {
    Collections.sort(courses, new Comparator<Course>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Course o1, Course o2) {
            return o1.getClassList().size() - o2.getClassList().size();
        }
    });
    for (int indexOfLargest = 1; indexOfLargest < courses.size(); indexOfLargest ++) {
        if (courses.get(indexOfLargest - 1).getClassList().size() > courses.get(indexOfLargest).getClassList().size())
            return courses.subList(0, indexOfLargest);
    }
    return courses;
}
```